# SKlearn linear regression coeffs equals 0

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

There was a problem in the simplest example of linear regression. At the output, the coefficients are zero, what do I do wrong? Thanks for the help.

```
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [25,50,75,100]
y = [10.5,17,23.25,29]
pred = [27,41,22,33]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'pred':pred})
x = df['x'].values.reshape(1,-1)
y = df['y'].values.reshape(1,-1)
pred = df['pred'].values.reshape(1,-1)
plt.scatter(x,y,color='black')
clf = lm.LinearRegression(fit_intercept =True)
clf.fit(x,y)


m=clf.coef_[0]
b=clf.intercept_
print("slope=",m, "intercept=",b)
```

Output:

```
slope= [ 0.  0.  0.  0.] intercept= [ 10.5   17.    23.25  29.  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think it through for a second. Given that you have multiple coefficients returned suggests you have multiple factors. Since it's a single regression, the problem lies in the shape of your input data. Your original reshaping made the class think you had 4 variables and only one observation per variable.

Try something like this:

```
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([25,99,75,100, 3, 4, 6, 80])[..., np.newaxis]
y = np.array([10.5,17,23.25,29, 1, 2, 33, 4])[..., np.newaxis]

clf = lm.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(x,y)
clf.coef_
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.09399429]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jrjames83 has already explained in his answer after reshaping (`.reshape(1,-1)`) you were feeding a data set containing one sample (row) and four features (columns):

```
In [103]: x.shape
Out[103]: (1, 4)
```

most probably you wanted to reshape it this way:

```
In [104]: x = df['x'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

In [105]: x.shape
Out[105]: (4, 1)
```

so that you would have four samples and one feature...

alternatively you could pass DataFrame columns to your model as follows (no need to pollute your memory with additional variables):

```
In [98]: clf = lm.LinearRegression(fit_intercept =True)

In [99]: clf.fit(df[['x']],df['y'])
Out[99]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)

In [100]: clf.coef_
Out[100]: array([0.247])

In [101]: clf.intercept_
Out[101]: 4.5
```